# How the people picker recognizing users and groups for 2 domains with confidence relationship?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a domain A and another B. Both have a relationship of trust.
Then I think my Sharepoint site within domain A and added a PeoplePicker field. The detail is that in the PeoplePicker field when I search for users of domain B (User by user) if it recognizes them, but when I search for a group in domain B (User group) I get an error saying "This user does not exist or is not unique".

I want to be able to add user groups from domain B from the PeoplePicker field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need configure people picker to search other domain.

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv domain:DnsName,user,password -url http:// webapp
```

Check the thread for more details.

http://www.sharepointdoug.com/2014/06/how-to-configure-people-picker-in.html